# Is the codomain of random variable $X$ always equal to the domain of the associated p.d.f. (or p.m.f.)?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, random-variables, definition

A random variable $X$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to a measurable space $E$.

Is the codomain of random variable $X$ always equal to the domain of the associated p.d.f. $f$ (or p.m.f.)?

I think this must be the case in order for the notation $f(X)$, which is supposed to mean the composition of $f$ and $X$, to make sense.

This question arises after having gotten an answer to the other question: [Can we really compose random variables and probability density functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769270/168764).

Answer (score 0):

A random variable need not have a p.d.f.. If it has, then the p.d.f $f$ is by definition a measurable function defined on the **entire real line** such that $P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)dt$ for all $x$. Therefore $f(X)$ makes sense irrespective of the actual values attained by $X$. However $f$ is unique only up to sets of measure $0$ so for $f(X)$ to make sense we have to fix one measurable version of $f$.

Comment: Can you provide an example of when we would define or need a random variable without an associated pdf/pmf?

Comment: You can search for singular distribution functions or mixtures of distribution functions.